# give a nfa without ε-transitions corresponding to the Regular expression

Tags: finite-automata

Regular expression: (0 + 01)(ε + 1)1(ε + 0 + 1)*

I dont know if my answer to this is entirely right but please enlighten me if i'm way out of line.

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ &0&1&\\\hline
q0&\{q0\}&\{q1\}&\\\
q1&\{q1\}&\{q1\}&\
\end{array}

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression is equivalent to `0 1? 1? 1 (0+1)*`, which is equivalent to `0 1 (0+1)*`. So you just have to look for a zero and then a one at the beginning. If you see those, the string is acceptable.

You can do this with four states: `start`, `0`, `good`, and `bad`.

```
state |  0   |  1
------+------+------
start | 0    | bad
    0 | bad  | good
  bad | bad  | bad
 good | good | good
```

The only accepting state is `good`. The initial state is `start`. Note that this is in fact a DFA: you don't need any nondeterminism at all. (The only difference is, you can replace the `bad` state with an empty set in an NFA, and it won't change the meaning.)

The NFA you've come up with won't work, since it'll accept any number of zeroes at the beginning (including none, or two, or fifty), rather than exactly one.